# Google script: find value then set new value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make simple function. Got two sheets, one for manually entering data `sheetA` second is database `sheetB`.Name cell is always `B1`, surname is always `B2` both in `sheetA`. How I want this to work:

1. Search value is `B9` from `sheetA`
2. Find matching row in `sheetB`
3. Take value from matching row column `12`
4. Replace found value with value from `imie` + `nazwisko`

Here is the code:

```js
function Find() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheetA = ss.getSheetByName('A')
  const sheetB = ss.getSheetByName('B')

  const bData = sheetB.getRange(2,1,sheetA.getLastRow()-1,13).getValues()

  const name = sheetA.getRange("B1").getValue() 
  const surname = sheetA.getRange("B2").getValue() 

  const searchValue = sheetA.getRange("B9").getValue() 

  const matchRow = bData.find( r => r[1] == searchValue)
  const match = matchRow ? matchRow[12] : null 

}
```

I tried with

```js
sheetB.getRange(??).setValue(name + " " + surname)
```

It's working when I put exact range like `M2` but how to put `match` value in `getRange`?

Edit:

input and output `sheetA` (search cell always stays the same, for this example it's `1542`

| First name | Last name | car ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Emma | Brown | 1542 |

input `sheetB`:

| car ID | Year | Driver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3421 | 2019 | John Doe |
| 1542 | 2021 | Tom Meyer |
| 7652 | 2014 | Victoria Weber |

output `sheetB`:

| car ID | Year | Driver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3421 | 2019 | John Doe |
| 1542 | 2021 | Emma Brown |
| 7652 | 2014 | Victoria Weber |

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: column 12 is r[11]

Comment: @Tanaike added sample input and output, maybe now you will understand what I'm looking for

Comment: No actually I don't

Comment: Just look on sample tables. Two sheets, one fore entering data second is database. Search value is always C1 cell in this example,

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing your sample input and output situations. From your added information, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you, It's working how I wanted to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve your provided "input sheetB:" using "SheetA".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetNameA = "SheetA"; // Please set your source sheet name.
  const sheetNameB = "SheetB"; // Please set your destination sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetA = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameA);
  const sheetB = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameB);
  const obj = new Map(sheetA.getRange("A2:C" + sheetA.getLastRow()).getValues().map(r => [r[2], `${r[0]} ${r[1]}`]));
  const range = sheetB.getRange("A2:C" + sheetB.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues().map(r => [obj.get(r[0]) || r[2]]);
  range.offset(0, 2, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, I think that your provided output situation is obtained by your input situation.

#### Note:

- **From your added sample tables, in this answer, it supposes that values of `First name` and `car ID` are existing in a cell "A1" of "SheetA" and "SheetB", respectively. Please be careful about this.**

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)